# Can i use 2 different functions returning different data types inside my template function code?

Tags: c++11, templates

I am trying to templatize some of my code and am not sure if i am doing it correct way ?

```
template <typename T>
class User
{
    public:
    template <typename T>
    void foo() {
A* pa = funcA();
        OR
        B* pb = funcB();
        //common code follows
         ....
         ....
         ....
};


User<Atype> C1;
User<Btype> C2;
```

In the above code I am looking as to how to define foo() as to be able to use 
either of A* pa = funcA() or B* pb = funcB() based on how the class is instantiated. C1 should be able to use A* pa = funcA() and C2 should be able to use B* pb = funcB().

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but there is various options. Normally it is best to avoid designs that result in needing different named functions, or conceptually different operations.

For example if both A and B had a member or static function `foo`, then you could call that (`x.foo()`, `T::foo()`, etc.) instead of having the separately named `funcA` and `funcB`. Or similarly, in the case of parameters you can use function overloading (as you can't overload on the return type), such as `std::to_string`, and sometimes using templates as well such as `std::swap`.

Otherwise, if you need to support completely different things, then there are many options.

1. You can specialise `foo` to have different implementations for different types. This is often not particularly ideal if you are planning to use many different types with a template function or class. In some cases you might specialise the entire class, and there is also partial specialisation.

   ```
   class A {};
   class B {};

   A *funcA();
   B *funcB();

   template <typename T>
   class User
   {
   public:
       void foo();
   };

   template<> void User<A>::foo()
   {
       auto a = funcA();
       // ...
   }
   template<> void User<B>::foo()
   {
       auto ab = funcB();
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Similar to 1, you can have a separate template function or class that is specialised.

   ```
    class A {};
    class B {};

    A *funcA();
    B *funcB();

    template<class T> T *funcGeneric();
    template<> A *funcGeneric<A>() { return funcA(); }
    template<> B *funcGeneric<B>() { return funcB(); }

    template <typename T>
    class User
    {
     public:
        void foo()
        {
            auto p = funcGeneric<T>();
        }
    };
   ```

   Or with a class, which can be useful if you have multiple methods or pieces of information. For a single method, the call operator is often overloaded.

   ```
   template<class T> class FuncGeneric;
   template<> class FuncGeneric<A>
   {
   public:
       A *operator()()const { return funcA(); }
   };
   template<> class FuncGeneric<B>
   {
   public:
       B *operator()()const { return funcB(); }
   };

   template <typename T>
   class User
   {
   public:
       void foo()
       {
           auto p = FuncGeneric<T>()();
       }
   };
   ```
3. Extending on 2, but you pass the "adapter" as a template parameter itself. This is one you see in the STL a fair bit, with things like `std::map` taking the `Compare` parameter (default `std::less`), `unique_ptr` taking a deleter (with `std::default_delete` calling `delete`), hash functions, etc.

   ```
   template<class T> class FuncGeneric;
   template<> class FuncGeneric<A>
   {
   public:
       A *operator()()const { return funcA(); }
   };
   template<> class FuncGeneric<B>
   {
   public:
       B *operator()()const { return funcB(); }
   };

   template <class T, class Func = FuncGeneric<T>>
   class User
   {
   public:
       void foo()
       {
           auto p = Func()();
       }
   };
   ```
4. In some cases you might pass the function itself. More common for functions rather than classes, for example many of the algorithms (e.g. `find_if`) do this.

   ```
   template <class T, class Func>
   class User
   {
   public:
       User(Func func) : func(func) {}
       void foo()
       {
           auto p = func();
       }
   private:
       Func func;
   };
   int main()
   {
       User<A, A*(*)()> user(&funcA);
   }
   ```
5. Functions can also be a template parameter themselves, although this is fairly uncommon.

   ```
   template <class T, T*(*Func)()>
   class User
   {
   public:
       void foo()
       {
           auto p = Func();
       }
   };
   int main()
   {
       User<A, &funcA> user;
   }
   ```